# perl uri_escape_utf8 with arabic

Tags: perl, escaping, arabic

I am trying to escape some Arabic to LWP::UserAgent. I am testing this with a script below:

```
my $files = "/home/root/temp.txt";
unlink ($files);
open (OUTFILE, '>>', $files);
my $text = "ضثصثضصثشس";
print OUTFILE uri_escape_utf8($text)."\n";
close (OUTFILE);
```

However, this seems to cause the following:

```
%C3%96%C3%8B%C3%95%C3%8B%C3%96%C3%95%C3%8B%C3%94%C3%93
```

which is not correct. Any pointers to what I need to do in order to escape this correctly?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Regards,

Olli

Comment: Is your Perl file encoded as UTF-8? Did you `use utf8`? If I do that, I get `%D8%B6%D8%AB%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B6%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B4%D8%B3` – is that correct? (It roundtrips correctly)

Answer (score 4):

Perl consideres your source file to be encoded as Latin-1 until you tell it to `use utf8`. If we do that, the string `"ضثصثضصثشس"` does not contain some jumbled bytes, but is rather a string of *codepoints*.

The `uri_escape_utf8` expects a string of codepoints (not bytes!), encodes them, and then URI-escapes them. Ergo, the correct thing to do is

```
use utf8;
use URI::Escape;
print uri_escape_utf8("ضثصثضصثشس"), "\n";
```

Output: `%D8%B6%D8%AB%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B6%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B4%D8%B3`

---

If we fail to `use utf8`, then `uri_escape_utf8` gets a string of bytes (which are accidentally encoded in UTF8), so we should have used `uri_escape`:

```
die "This is the wrong way to do it";
use URI::Escape;
print uri_escape("ضثصثضصثشس"), "\n";
```

which produces the same output as above – but only by accident.

Using `uri_escape_utf8` whith a bytestring (that would *decode* to arabic characters) produces the totally wrong

```
%C3%98%C2%B6%C3%98%C2%AB%C3%98%C2%B5%C3%98%C2%AB%C3%98%C2%B6%C3%98%C2%B5%C3%98%C2%AB%C3%98%C2%B4%C3%98%C2%B3
```

because this effectively double-encodes the data. It is the same as

```
use utf8;
use URI::Escape;
use Encode;
print uri_escape(encode "utf8", encode "utf8", "ضثصثضصثشس"), "\n";
```

**Edit:** So you used CP-1256, which is a non-portable single byte encoding. It is unable to encode arbitrary Unicode characters, and should therefore be avoided along with other pre-Unicode encodings. You didn't declare your encoding, so perl thinks you meant Latin-1. This means that what you saw as `"ضثصثضصثشس"` was actually the byte stream `D6 CB D5 CB D6 D5 CB D4 D3`, which decodes to some unprintable junk in Latin-1.

**Edit:** So you want to decode command line arguments. The [`Encode::Locale`](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode%3a%3aLocale) module should manage this. Before accessing any parameters from `@ARGV`, do

```
use Encode::Locale;
decode_argv(Encode::FB_CROAK); # possibly: BEGIN { decode_argv(...) }
```

or use the `locale` pseudoencoding which it provides:

```
my $decoded_string = decode "locale" $some_binary_data;
```

Use this as a part in the overall strategy of decoding all input, and always encoding your output.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I try your solution I get whole heap of "Malformed UTF-8 character" errors. Now, I assume this is because my system character set is ar_SA.cp1256. There is no option to change the system character set. Do I need to somehow covert from ar_SA.cp1256 to utf-8 before escaping?

Comment: Nothing in my post has to do with your locale. Just make sure to save your Perl scripts as UTF-8 in your editor, and use the first solution I've shown. PS: I just verified that your script was originally saved in CP1256 – this code page includes the ASCII character set, so simple Perl scripts work as expected. However, perl consideres this to be Latin-1 and thus misinterprets your file. Saving your scripts as UTF-8 is the only portable solution.

Comment: Sorry, will explain a bit more what I am trying to do. The above is just a test, but my final requirement is for the string to come in as an argument, when the script is executed from the shell. So, I assume if the environment is set to CP1256, the argument will also come in as CP1256 and I will need to convert it?

Comment: @user567602 This information was very useful. You can use the Encode::Locale module to do this, which you need to install from CPAN. Do not hardcode a specific encoding, unless you want to make your script totally unportable. You may also want to read about the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) when asking future questions.